# Django channels create a separate task that sends message to group at intervals

Tags: python, django, multithreading, websocket, django-channels

Essentially I am trying to create a real time applications for teams with Django channels. What happens is that there is a physics simulator that runs on the server and then sends the game state to be displayed on the client machines. What I need is a function that runs every 1/20 seconds on the server and then sends an output to each socket in a group. What I am currently thinking of doing is using threading to spin up a task (only needs to run for 60s total) which runs the physics simulation and then waits for the remaining time until the next execution. But I can guess that there is a real way to do this with Django channels which I can't find in the documentation.